# "ERROR: 57014: canceling statement due to user request" Npgsql

Tags: postgresql, command, dapper, npgsql

I am having this *phantom* problem in my application where one in every 5 request on a specific page (on an ASP.NET MVC application) throws this error:

```
Npgsql.NpgsqlException: ERROR: 57014: canceling statement due to user request
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlState.<ProcessBackendResponses>d__0.MoveNext()
   at Npgsql.ForwardsOnlyDataReader.GetNextResponseObject(Boolean cleanup)
   at Npgsql.ForwardsOnlyDataReader.GetNextRow(Boolean clearPending)
   at Npgsql.ForwardsOnlyDataReader.Read()
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.GetReader(CommandBehavior cb)
   ...
```

On the npgsql github page I found the following bug report: [615](https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/615)

It says there:

> Regardless of what exactly is happening with Dapper, there's
>   definitely a race condition when cancelling commands. Part of this is
>   by design, because of PostgreSQL: cancel requests are totally
>   "asynchronous" (they're delivered via an unrelated socket, not as part
>   of the connection to be cancelled), and you can't restrict the
>   cancellation to take effect only on a specific command. In other
>   words, if you want to cancel command A, by the time your cancellation
>   is delivered command B may already be in progress and it will be
>   cancelled instead.

Although they have made *"changes to hopefully make cancellations much safer"* in Npgsql 3.0.2 my current code is incompatible with this version because the need of migration described [here](http://www.npgsql.org/doc/migration-3.0.html).

**My current workaround (stupid)**: I have commented the code in Dapper that says `command.Cancel();` and the problem seems to be gone.

```
if (reader != null)
                {
                    if (!reader.IsClosed && command != null)
                    {
                        //command.Cancel();
                    }
                    reader.Dispose();
                    reader = null;
                }
```

Is there a better solution to the problem? And secondly what am I loosing with the current fix (except that I have to remember the change every time I update Dapper)?

Configuration:
NET45,
Npgsql 2.2.5,
Postgresql 9.3

Comment: Why are you executing query cancels in the first place? What problem are you trying to solve by doing so?

Comment: @CraigRinger This code is part of the Micro ORM that I use - Dapper. It is part of the Dispose method. I guess the reader is not closing properly and this is the reason to call the command.Cancel(). Source code can be found here https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net/blob/master/Dapper%20NET40/SqlMapper.cs#L4497

Comment: Sending a statement cancel as part of `Dispose` is horrible. Seriously? That's just a bug, plain and simple. Run, don't walk, away from that code. You should report a bug to the ORM developers ... then preferably find a saner one.

Comment: Thank you @CraigRinger! I will report the issue to the developers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found why my code didn't dispose the reader, resulting in calling `command.Cancel()`. This only happens with `QueryMultiple` method when not every `refcursor` is read.

Changing the code from:

```
using (var multipleResults = connection.QueryMultiple("schema.getuserbysocialsecurity", new { socialSecurityNumber }))
{
    var client = multipleResults.Read<Client>().SingleOrDefault();

    if (client != null)
    {
        client.Address = multipleResults.Read<Address>().Single();
    }

    return client;
}
```

To:

```
using (var multipleResults = connection.QueryMultiple("schema.getuserbysocialsecurity", new { socialSecurityNumber }))
{
    var client = multipleResults.Read<Client>().SingleOrDefault();
    var address = multipleResults.Read<Address>().SingleOrDefault();

    if (client != null)
    {
        client.Address = address;
    }

    return client;
}
```

This fixed the issue and now the reader is properly disposed and `command.Cancel()` is not invoked.

Hope this helps anyone else!

**UPDATE**

The [npgsql docs for version 2.2](http://www.npgsql.org/doc/manual-2.2.html) states:

> Npgsql is able to ask the server to cancel commands in progress. To do
>   this, call the NpgsqlCommand’s Cancel method. Note that another thread
>   must handle the request as the main thread will be blocked waiting for
>   command to finish. Also, the main thread will raise an exception as a
>   result of user cancellation. (The error code is 57014.)

I have also posted an [issue](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net/issues/344) on the Dapper github page.

Comment: We've encountered this problem when misusing Dapper. Specifically, it was because we were doing INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE commands with Query instead of Execute. I think that other providers my be more tolerant to this kind of misuse.